# find latitude and longtitude in the string

Tags: ios, ios5, dictionary, ios6

Imagine that you are adding annotations on map(View) and appending latitude and longititude string and putting it into URL to get each individual map annotation information.
My problem is, once I choose an annotation to remove, how I am going to find chosen annotation latitude and longtitude in the string  which is for URL request.

for example

```
www.something.com/39.001,29.002;34.0567,-32,0091;56.987,76.435
```

then assume that you deleted annotation `34.0567,-32,0091`

how you update your string in the following

```
www.something.com/39.001,29.002;56.987,76.435
```

Comment: Just to make things clear... Are you looking for a way to build a url containing a list of your map's annotations (coordinates)?

Comment: Ok I know that you've chosen an answer, but there is a better way to do this. So I'll post one as a reference.

Comment: @Alladinian are you referring to creating an NSMutableArray of the placemarks currently in the URL, then removing the placemark to be deleted and recreating the URL? If so, it's a bit extreme to do that under such a small circumstance.

Comment: @max_ Actually I was thinking to serialize the data each time in order  to construct a url with the coordinates. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn the URL into as `NSMutableString` in order to 'edit' the URL, and then replace the occurrences of the placemark within that string. Then turn the string back into a URL:

```
NSURL *currentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.something.com/39.001,29.002;34.0567,-32,0091;56.987,76.435"];

NSMutableString *absolute = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[currentURL absoluteString]];
[absolute replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"34.0567,-32,0091;" withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [absolute length])];

NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:absolute];

NSLog(@"My new URL = %@", newURL.absoluteString);
```

Edit---> Updated code including index of the changed placemark.

```
NSString *domain = @"www.something.com/";
NSURL *currentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"www.something.com/39.001,29.002;34.0567,-32,0091;56.987,76.435"];

NSMutableString *absolute = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[currentURL absoluteString]];
[absolute replaceOccurrencesOfString:domain withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [absolute length])];

NSArray *placemarks = [absolute componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];

NSString *placemarkToRemove = @"34.0567,-32,0091";

NSUInteger index = [placemarks indexOfObject:placemarkToRemove];

[absolute replaceOccurrencesOfString:[placemarkToRemove stringByAppendingString:@";"] withString:@"" options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [absolute length])];

NSURL *newURL = [NSURL URLWithString:absolute];

NSLog(@"Placemark Index = %u; My new URL = %@", index, newURL.absoluteString);
```

Comment: Hello Max thanks a lot for giving such an awesome answer. [absolute replaceOccurrencesOfString:@"34.0567,-32,0091" withString:@"" options:? range:?]; what would be the question mark for my case

Comment: Hello Max, how could I know which object index removed? for example in the above case second object deleted. How do I know that?

Comment: Updated my answer. The `index` variable will hold your index.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to this. Since you're  using a map with annotations you can get the list of annotations at anytime and then pass them to a method to construct your url:

```
- (NSURL *)makeUrlFromAnnotations:(NSArray *)annotations
{
    NSString *baseUrl = @"www.something.com/";
    NSMutableArray *annotationStrings = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (id <MKAnnotation> annotation in annotations)
    {
     [annotationStrings addObject:
      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f,%f",
       annotation.coordinate.latitude,
       annotation.coordinate.longitude]
     ];
    }

    return [NSURL URLWithString:[baseUrl stringByAppendingPathComponent:[annotationStrings componentsJoinedByString:@";"]]];
}
```

Then, each time you want a url with your coordinates just call:

```
NSURL *url = [self makeUrlFromAnnotations:self.myMapview.annotations];
//Or whatever property is your mapview
```